# Move Data from Form Response Sheet to Different Sheet using Button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have data in "Form Response Sheet". When user submit the form data saved in "Form Response Sheet". I want to move data from "Form Response Sheet" to "verified Form Response" sheet when user mark true in column w and Press "Submit" button. The row should be deleted from the "Form Response sheet" and Should be moved to Verified Form Response sheet.

The Verified Form Response Sheet contains daily data which was moved from Form Response Sheet. The moved data should be moved after the data earlier moved. The Sheet is also shared with my team member. The Script I used is not running with him.

The link of the sheet is as below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUUEZ7sSjBy-WWL3TZt8l6sqtrEBn3dZ03iRDTY1bF0/edit?usp=sharing

The script I am using is as below:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Verified Form Responses");
  
  var pasteSheet_size=pasteSheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  var source_size=copySheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  var source_range = copySheet.getRange(2,1,source_size,copySheet.getLastColumn());

  var move_data = source_range.getValues().filter(row=>row[22]==true);
  var source_data = source_range.getValues().filter(row=>row[22]==false);
  pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet_size+1,1,move_data.length,move_data[0].length).setValues(move_data);
  
  source_range.clearContent();
  copySheet.getRange(2,1,source_data.length,source_data[0].length).setValues(source_data);
        
}
```

Comment: Could you specify at which point are you stuck? What is your current issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

- Your goal is to move data between a **form responses** sheet to
  another sheet. The issue is that you need to **remove** the row after
  you transfer the entries from the form responses sheet, otherwise you
  will end up with a response sheet full o blank rows on the top (as it is the case right
  now).
- Also the current solution you use depends on the size of column
  A in `Form responses 1` sheet. Meaning that if you have blank rows in
  that sheet, you will get back the wrong number of rows.

---

### Explanation / Solution:

The **first step** towards the solution is to find the indexes that **column W** (checkboxes column) contains **true**. To achieve that, you can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
  const w_vals = src_sh.getRange('W2:W'+src_sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const inds = w_vals.reduce(
  (out, bool, index) => bool ? out.concat(index) : out, 
  []
  )
```

`inds` contains the indexes of the rows you want to move to the other sheet. Since we start counting from `W2`, the desired row will be given by `inds[i]+2`.

---

The **second step** is to iterate over `inds`. In each iteration, we **store** the data that we want to move into the `data` array and then we **delete** that row:

```
var temp = src_sh.getRange(inds[i]+2,1,1,src_sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
data.push(temp)
src_sh.deleteRow(inds[i]+2);
```

Keep in mind that the for loop iterates **backwards**, because every time we delete a row we change the structure of the sheet and `inds` wouldn't correspond to the correct row.

---

Finally, we efficiently (using `setValues`) **copy** the `data` to destination sheet:

`dst_sh.getRange(dst_sh_size+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);`

---

### Snippet:

Before you use this solution, **delete** all the top empty rows in the `Form responses 1` sheet (rows 2-108).

```
function CopyInfo() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const src_sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  const dst_sh = ss.getSheetByName("Verified Form Responses");
  const dst_sh_size=dst_sh.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  
  const w_vals = src_sh.getRange('W2:W'+src_sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const inds = w_vals.reduce(
  (out, bool, index) => bool ? out.concat(index) : out, 
  []
  )
   
  const data = [];  
  if ( inds.length != 0) {
  for (let i = inds.length -1 ; i>=0; i--){
  var temp = src_sh.getRange(inds[i]+2,1,1,src_sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  data.push(temp)
  src_sh.deleteRow(inds[i]+2);
  }
    
   dst_sh.getRange(dst_sh_size+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);     
  }
}
```

Comment: Script is working with me. But this sheet is being used by other team member which click submit button. When he click the button, script doesn't run. It ask for authorization. Please suggest.

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo Does the other user have edit access to the form sheet? Can he delete for example manually a row? If yes, then make sure that the other user gave permission to the script to be executed on his behalf.

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo there is nothing wrong with the script. The other user has to give permission to the script like every user needs to do with every script. You just need to give him edit access. Please let me now if the user allowed access to the script.

Comment: I have given access to him with Editor Right.

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo make sure that you haven't hidden the sheet from that user or you haven't applied protection to the sheets. The user might have edit access but the sheet might be protected or hidden and therefore the user is not able to edit. But anyway, if this also does not work I am afraid that no-one can help you in this post. Could you please post a different question regarding this issue and also since my answer solved your original question accept it and upvote it if you like :)